# Difference between cat * and cat * >>

Tags: files, cat

To merge multiple files in a dir I have tried:

```
cat * myfile.log
```

but this seems to just merge line and line and is thus very slow

So using instead:

```
cat * >> bigfile
```

merges the files much faster (from [combine multiple files into one file?](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/combine-multiple-files-into-one-file-446299/)).

What is the difference between each version of merging multiple files?

Comment: Your first snippet just prints to the console, I'm wondering why you're comparing it with the second - they don't do the same thing at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`cat * myfile.log` is going concatenate all the files in the directory (and "myfile.log" twice since it's included in the `*` *and* you named it) and print them to the screen (standard output).

`cat * >> bigfile` is going to concatenate all the files in the directory (`*` = everything) and append them to a file named "bigfile" (or write them to that file if it doesn't already exist).

(This answer assumes you didn't mean `cat * > myfile.log`)

If you want to see how long a process takes you can prefix the command with `time` and then you can compare the two.

Comment: +1 To make it clearer: output to the console is much much slower than output to a file, even more so because the file could likely still be in disk cache (RAM) when the process is complete.

Comment: `*` expands to all the filenames in the current directory _except the hidden ones_, unless the shell option `dotglob` is set.

Comment: And again because `*` includes `bigfile`, `cat * >>bigfile` would, depending on the `cat` implementation and the names sizes of the files involved, possibly loop indefinitely copying `bigfile` into itself or stop with or without an error.